# nginx error log in custom location result in Permission denied (when starting up) on CentOS 7 in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, centos7

I am using an AWS EC2 (c3.xlarge) instance with CentOS 7.x and these are my mount points:

```
[centos@ip-10-0-4-119 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  1.5G  6.6G  18% /
devtmpfs        3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.5G   17M  3.5G   1% /run
tmpfs           3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdb        40G   49M   38G   1% /mnt
tmpfs           707M     0  707M   0% /run/user/1000
```

The root partition `/` is 8gb (for the OS) and I have a 40gb drive mounted on `/mnt` for the website files. This is a standard setup.

I logged in as root (using `sudo su -`) and changed the ownership of `/mnt` to `centos:centos` (default account you login into).

in this dir, made another directory to store all the error logs here: `/mnt/errors` (dir perm is 755).

Nginx was installed the `nginx.conf` has the following lines:

```
user             centos;
worker_processes 4;
error_log        /mnt/errors/nginx-errors.log crit;
pid              /var/run/nginx.pid;
```

When I start the nginx server with this command: **systemctl start nginx.service** I get the following errors:

```
[centos@ip-10-0-4-119 ~]$ sudo systemctl status nginx
â— nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-11-11 02:20:14 UTC; 7min ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 10394 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 11 02:20:14 ip-10-0-4-119.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Nov 11 02:20:14 ip-10-0-4-119.localdomain nginx[10394]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Nov 11 02:20:14 ip-10-0-4-119.localdomain nginx[10394]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/mnt/errors/nginx-errors.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
Nov 11 02:20:14 ip-10-0-4-119.localdomain nginx[10394]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Nov 11 02:20:14 ip-10-0-4-119.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 11 02:20:14 ip-10-0-4-119.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
Nov 11 02:20:14 ip-10-0-4-119.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Nov 11 02:20:14 ip-10-0-4-119.localdomain systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

Why am I not able to use a custom location to store the nginx errors?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the directory where logs will go is readable, writable and executable by the nginx user since that'll be the owner of the nginx worker processes. here's what my nginx log directory looks like:

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-1 opt]# ls -ld /var/log/nginx/
drwx------ 2 nginx nginx 4096 Nov 11 03:27 /var/log/nginx/
```

if that doesn't make sense, you can do this:
chmod -R 755 /mnt/errors
chown -R nginx:nginx /mnt/errors

HTH